# Android app & GoogleMap :

Tags: android, google-maps

I got this class

```
public class GoogleMapActivity extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    }
}
```

and I get an error in editor - **"MapActivity cannot be resolvet to a type"**.

This [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview) says that I have to extend this particular class.

I mention that I have specified in manifest that I need google map library like this

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

Comment: make sure you have created project by selecting google api lib from Properties->Android

Comment: Oh, about that.. I payed attention to AVD (so it is a API based one). I am not shure I created the project itself in this manner. Can I convert it somehow at this point? :) Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, that was a stupid question. I already did that.

Comment: Project-Properties-Android -> Select API version.

Comment: this is not stupid question most of time we get same error as you are getting when we create project without selecting google API at the time when we create project

Comment: If you post your comment as an answer I would accept it. In that tutorial, as I read, it doesn't specify very clearly this aspect. Or I read it very superficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have Created your project by selecting **Google API SDK** . if not then see this tutorial for how we Create Android Google Map Application  :

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-working-with-google-maps/